# Microsoft Graph Toolkit People Picker Read-only Property

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am using Microsoft Graph Toolkit People Picker Component as illustrated in the documentation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/people-picker][1].

All the functionality is working fine but unable to set the people picker to disabled/read-only. I have tried `disabled="true" but no luck. Anybody came across similar scenario?

Also note that I am using @microsoft/mgt-react package from NPM

Comment: In past i tried using "disabled=true" property and it worked.

Comment: Looks like we don't support disabled right now, but we could add that in the next release. Could you create a feature request here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Needs%3A+Triage+%3Amag%3A%2C+feature-request&template=feature_request.md&title=